# ¿Porqué no me escribe la lista?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Yo tengo esto:

Mi archivo txt:

```
1,paella,14000,30,0
2,milanesa napolitana,13000,30,0
3,pollo alla piazzaiola,16000,30,0
4,Pasta con calabacín y pecorino,15000,30,0
5,Pasta boloñesa y berenjena,15000,30,0
6,Lasaña de espinacas y ricotta,15000,30,0
7,Solomillo de cerdo con salsa gorgonzola,16000,30,0
8,Piadina de verduras y queso de cabra,20000,30,0
9,Gaseosa,3000,50,0
10,Agua,2500,50,0
11,Malteada,5000,50,0
12,Te,4000,50,0
13,Cheese Cake de Guayaba,10000,35,0
14,Profiteroles,7000,40,0
15,Flan Napolitano,11000,33,0
16,Mousse de Chocolate,12000,40,0
```

Y escribo la lista justo en el while que está abajo:

```java
try {
    ptrF = null;
    File archivo = new File("Menu.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String c;
    while ((c = br.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(c, ",");
        int codi = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
        String name = st.nextElement().toString();
        double prec = Double.parseDouble(st.nextElement().toString());
        int canti = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
        int vent = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
        UpdateFile u = new UpdateFile(codi, name, prec, canti, vent);
        if (ptrF == null) {
            ptrF = u;
        } else {
            UpdateFile p = ptrF;
            while (p.link != null) {
                p = p.link;
            }
            p.link = u;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    UpdateFile u = ptrF;
    while (u != null) {
        System.out.println(u.codigo + "," + u.nombre);
        u = u.link              
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Vista.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Pero al momento de escribir la lista no me escribe nada, agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Si podrías compartir el contenido de "Menu.txt" sería una gran ayuda. Aclara por favor si "no me escribe nada" significa que ni te sale una entrada en el Logger. ¿Donde esperas que se te escribe una lista, y a donde? ¿Log? ¿System.out? En este momento no veo ninguna parte en tu código donde tuvieras un bucle o while en que se podría mostrar una lista.

Comment: No me sale el System.out que tengo abajo en el while...

Comment: Un [mcve] sería ideal.

Comment: Revisando tu LinkedList casera, igual debería funcionar. Te aseguraste que la ruta al archivo esta correcta y que el Logger esta bien configurado (para que no se te escapa si hay una excepción)?

Comment: Sería amable si podrías compartir el `Menu.txt`en forma de copiar/pegar en vez de un imagen. Lo hace más fácil de comprobar tu código.

Comment: Revisando tu LinkedList casera, igual debería funcionar. Te aseguraste que la ruta al archivo esta correcta y que el Logger esta bien configurado (para que no se te escapa si hay una excepción)?

Comment: @StefanNolde Si, lo comprobe. Ademas ese codigo lo tenia dentro de una subrutina, lo extraño es que dentro de la subrutina me lo escribia pero en el programa cuando llamo a la subrutina es como si los parametros no hubieran cambiado.

Comment: Trata ser más claro: Si el código te funcionó (y aun un poco ofuscado esta correcto) te quedan 2 fuentes de error: la ruta del archivo (y una excepción que no ves) y la salida para la consola. Para reproducir se necesita más entorno, Te agrego una manera de comprobarlo en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Minimiza tus fuentes de error con un poco más salida:

```
try {
        ptrF = null;
        File archivo = new File("Menu.txt");
        // comprueba si tu ruta esta correcta y que ves la salida stdout
        System.out.println(String.format("Archivo %s existe? - %b",
            archivo.getAbsoluteFile(), archivo.exists()));
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String c;
        while ((c = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // comprueba la entrada
            System.out.println(String.format("Entrada: %s", c));
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(c, ",");
            int codi = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
            String name = st.nextElement().toString();
            double prec = Double.parseDouble(st.nextElement().toString());
            int canti = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
            int vent = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
            UpdateFile u = new UpdateFile(codi, name, prec, canti, vent);
            if (ptrF == null) {
                ptrF = u;
            }else{
                UpdateFile p = ptrF;
                while(p.link != null){
                    p = p.link;
                }
                p.link = u;
            }            
        }
        br.close();
        UpdateFile u = ptrF;
        while(u != null){
              System.out.println(u.codigo+","+u.nombre);
              u = u.link              
        }

} catch (IOException ex) {
      e.printStackTrace(); // si hay un problema en la configuración del Logger
      Logger.getLogger(Vista.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```